# How to make sbt-native-packager combine two layers of docker image

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I'm using sbt-native-packager to build a docker image from a Scala application.
There are two layers of similar size in the resulting image:

```
docker history --no-trunc docker.example.com/scala-app

...
b49580a36beb6c7cd020ad006954f245aebf82041d3e79eff1517fdbf58ae6cd   About an hour ago   chown -R daemon:daemon . 125.2 MB             
f12b3a929ded4161044642e117114b57889613d77186a0a727862ab5a44af5e3   About an hour ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD dir:678c325d24285ae96f682c6abc3d71cc8a17ee6267a2db4fff232fcaaa5dec13 in /opt  125.2 MB
...
```

I assume that these two layers differ only in ownership (chown -R daemon:daemon .). The problem is that both of them are downloaded during pulling.
Is there a way two combine these two layers into one for the sake of image size?

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to change this behaviour by overriding dockerCommands:

```
 lazy val root = myProject("scala-app", ".")
    .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin).settings(dockerSettings: _*)
    .settings(dockerCommands in Docker := dockerCommands.value.filterNot {
      // remove chown command because it creates redundant image layer
      case ExecCmd("RUN", args @ _*) => args.contains("chown")
      // don't filter the rest
      case cmd                       => false
    })
```

This solution is described in DockerPlugin documentation at http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html#remove-commands.